# Escape $ character inside a MS SQL query in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a situation under which I have to use $ (dollar sign) inside a MS SQL query since the table is named this way (e.g. ***[My company name$Fixed Asset].[Description]***), but PHP recognizes part ***"$Fixed"*** as a variable and then later on when I try to execute the code in the browser it throws an error e.g. "***Notice: Undefined variable: Fixed***".

How do I escape this character?

Here is the part of the code I am trying to use:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if ($_POST['password'] === 'mypass') {

            $result = mssql_query("SET ANSI_NULLS ON;");
            $result1 = mssql_query("SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;"); 
            $query = mssql_query("

TRUNCATE TABLE [fixed_assets].[dbo].[fa_masterdata];

INSERT INTO [fixed_assets].[dbo].[fa_masterdata]

SELECT  
[My company name$Fixed Asset].[No]
,[My company name$Fixed Asset].[Description]
,[Search Description]
,[Description 2]
,[Location Code]
,[Vendor No_]
,[My company name$FA Depreciation Book].[Disposal Date]
,[My company name$FA Location].[Name]
,[My company name$Comment Line].Code
,[My company name$Comment Line].Comment
FROM [SQL SERVER NAME\INSTANCE].[MY COMPANY].[dbo].[My company name$Fixed Asset]


full outer join [SQL SERVER NAME\INSTANCE].[MY COMPANY].[dbo].[My company name$FA Location]
on [My company name$Fixed Asset].[FA Location Code] = [My company name$FA Location].[Code]

full outer join [SQL SERVER NAME\INSTANCE].[MY COMPANY].[dbo].[Record Link]
on [My company name$Fixed Asset].[No_] = convert(varchar(100),SUBSTRING([Record Link].[Record ID],8,8))

full outer join [SQL SERVER NAME\INSTANCE].[MY COMPANY].[dbo].[My company name$Comment Line]
on [My company name$Comment Line].[No_] = [My company name$Fixed Asset].[No_]

full outer join [SQL SERVER NAME\INSTANCE].[MY COMPANY].[dbo].[My company name$FA Depreciation Book]
on [My company name$FA Depreciation Book].[Fa No_] = [My company name$Fixed Asset].[No_]

where [My company name$Fixed Asset].[No_] != null");

    echo "<br/><br/><div class='alert alert-success col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-2'><span>Fixed assets data imported from NAV successfully!!</span></div>";
            } else {
                echo "<br/><br/><span>Import failed! (wrong password entered?)";
            }
    }
    ?>
```

[image: ERROR SAMPLE]

Please advise. Any suggestion is more than welcome.
Thank you all.

Comment: can you show the PHP as well please. If you're building the query as a string I would suggest wrapping the string in single quotes ( ' ) instead of double quotes ( " ) then it will be taken literally instead of interpolated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the `$` and then it won't be read as a variable by PHP.

```
echo "\$test";
```

Demo: https://eval.in/605867 Vs. https://eval.in/605866 (which is empty because `$test` doesnt exist)

...

or since your query doesn't use single quotes just use single quotes for the string encapsulation.

```
echo '$test';
```

Comment: As an alternative, use single quotes: [https://eval.in/605868](https://eval.in/605868). That way, PHP won't interpret `$test` as a variable, but an ordinary string.

Comment: That will require changing the whole query, and I'm not sure mssql works with double quoted string encapsulation (I'd assume it does). Oh, there's been an update.. no single quote usage in the query.

Comment: Adding a backslash character in front of a dollar sign $ did the trick!   
I would never thought of this in a million years and that it would be interpreted correctly inside a MS SQL query ... inside PHP ... But hey, you learn new things every day ^_^ Thank you all for suggesting it!